# Mechanize: Follow links inside a div

Tags: python, html, mechanize

Whats the most pythonic way to make Mechanize follow links (`br.follow_link`) that are located inside a certain div? I know how to do it with a bit of help from BeautifulSoup but is there a way of doing it with Mechanize?

Sample div:

```
<div id="blah_links">
 <a href="LINK1" class="active">1</a> |
 <a href="LINK2">2</a> |
 <a href="LINK3">3</a> |
 <a href="LINK4">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problem recently and here is what i did

```
url = "www.somewhere.com"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)

encoded_data = UnicodeDammit(br.response().read(),isHTML=True).unicode
parser = lxml_html.fromstring(encoded_data)

soup_xpath = "//div[@id='BODYCON']//a/@href"
valid_links = soup.xpath(soup_xpath)
links  = [ link for link if link.url in valid_links ]
```