# Following links with Mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I would like to use the Mechanize python library to follow certain links in a website, but the only links I'm interested in are the ones in a `<div>` tag. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481091/mechanize-follow-links-inside-a-div) question is related, but they achieve it using the `lxml` parser, which I'm not familiar with, I'm more comfortable using BeautifulSoup.

I've located the relevant links using BeautifulSoup already, but I don't know how to use Mechanize (or something else) to follow these links. Is there a way to pass a string to Mechanize so that it will follow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple `open()` should be enough:

```
br.open('http://google.com')
```

Comment: That was a lot easier that I thought it would be!

Answer (score 1):

```
import mechanize
response = mechanize.urlopen("http://example.com/")
content = response.read() #The content is the code of the page (html)
```

Or, if you want to add things like headers:

```
import mechanize
request = mechanize.Request("http://example.com/")
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
content = response.read() #The content is the code of the page (html)
```